# does beam docstring in sympy accepts floats in apply_load () function

Tags: python-3.x, sympy

When trying to get deflection equation using sympy beam module in continuum mechanics, i get an error if I use float in location argument

```
from sympy.physics.continuum_mechanics.beam import Beam
from sympy import symbols, Piecewise
E, I = symbols ( 'E, I')
b = Beam (30, E, I)
b.apply_support (0, 'roller')
b.apply_support (10 , 'roller')
b.apply_support (30, 'roller')
b.apply_load (-10, 5, -1)   ## if 5. is changed to 5, deflection equation works?
b.apply_load (-10, 15, -1)  ## if 5. is changed to 5, deflection equation works?
R_0, R_10, R_30 = symbols ('R_0, R_10, R_30')
b.solve_for_reaction_loads (R_0, R_10, R_30)
b.load
b.shear_force ()
b.plot_shear_force ()
b.deflection ()
```

Does anyone know if above commented lines are valid, or I have to convert argument values into integers?

Comment: this is definitely a bug (probably related to the solver and floating point). Please, open an issue at: https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you may have to use integers otherwise (as in this case) an inconsistent set of equation might result which has no solution. In your case the equations to be solved are

```py
[C4, 10*C3 + C4 + 156.25, 30*C3 + C4 + 468.749999999996]
```

Because of rounding errors, the value of C3 calculated from the second equation is not the same as that from the 3rd so the EmptySet is returned as a solution.

Comment: Thank you smichr, this is helpful and definitely a better way of doing it, i was thinking to keep units in m same as beam docstring documentation however i can keep all units in N-mm instead, Cheers